# cloneNode vs innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to clone a template in a header using the [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) without success.
Here is my markup

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header"),
$templateHeader = document.querySelector("[data-template=header]");

header.innerHTML = $templateHeader.innerHTML;
```

```html
<header></header>

<!--templates-->
<template data-template=header>
  <div class=container>
    <menu class=row>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>items</a></li>
      <li><a>Reseller</a></li>
      <li><a>Shop</a></li>
    </menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

This works just fine

```
header.innerHTML = $templateHeader.innerHTML;
```

while this will not work

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header"),
$templateHeader = document.querySelector("[data-template=header]");

header.innerHTML = $templateHeader.cloneNode(true);
```

```html
<header></header>

<!--templates-->
<template data-template=header>
  <div class=container>
    <menu class=row>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>items</a></li>
      <li><a>Reseller</a></li>
      <li><a>Shop</a></li>
    </menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

even this

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header"),
$templateHeader = document.querySelector("[data-template=header]");

header.appendChild($templateHeader.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<header></header>

<!--templates-->
<template data-template=header>
  <div class=container>
    <menu class=row>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>items</a></li>
      <li><a>Reseller</a></li>
      <li><a>Shop</a></li>
    </menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

when i console.log `$templateHeader.cloneNode(true)` this is what i get

[image]

Can anyone help me understanding what i am doing wrong here?

**Note:** *i don't want to use jquery*

regards, Tambo

Comment: I'm failing to see the difference between the html snippets, what should it look like and what is it looking like? (__Edit__) Oh I see, after making a fiddle, the [latter](http://jsfiddle.net/c6x3mLm4/) simply returns the object meanwhile the [previous](http://jsfiddle.net/c6x3mLm4/1/) one properly displays the elements. You could try to parse the object?

Comment: i am trying to figure out how to achieve the result from demo 1 using cloneNode and or appendChild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have cloned the entire template and are trying to append the template to your header.  You don't want to do that, you want to append the content of the template.

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header"),
$templateHeader = document.querySelector("[data-template=header]");

header.appendChild($templateHeader.content.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<header></header>

<!--templates-->
<template data-template=header>
  <div class=container>
    <menu class=row>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>items</a></li>
      <li><a>Reseller</a></li>
      <li><a>Shop</a></li>
    </menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

That said, in a number of samples I found online, I found `importNode` used instead of `cloneNode`:

```
var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
```